# Display selected radio's value

Tags: templating, field

The issue arises from inline three buttons (Viewer, Video, Photo) via CSS.

The idea was to make the buttons more responsive for example if I want to display just one button than stretch to 100% width within the parent. Two buttons (50% each) and three buttons (33.33% each).

I guess if I setup radio field and the values are `displayOne`, `displayTwo` and `displayThree`.

```
{% for option in entry.viewerOption %}

{% if option in entry.viewerOption.value.selected(displayOne) %}
<a class=”single” href="#">Viewer</a>
{% else %}
<a class=”single” href="#">Photo</a>
{% else %}
<a class=”single” href="#">Video</a>
{% endif %}

{% else %}

{% if option in entry.viewerOption.value.selected(displayTwo) %}
<a class=”duel” href="#">Viewer</a>
<a class=”duel” href="#">Photo</a>
<a class=”duel” href="#">Video</a>
{% endif %}

{% else %}

{% if option in entry.viewerOption.value.selected(displayThree) %}
<a class=”triple” href="#">Viewer</a>
<a class=”triple” href="#">Photo</a>
<a class=”triple” href="#">Video</a>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I am not sure what is the best method to dynamically single, duel or triple buttons base on selected radio value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I totally get what you're trying to do, but if you want to cut down a bit of the code duplication in here a good start would be to use a [Twig macro](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tags/macro.html).

So you'd set up your macro like this:

```
{% macro input(cssClass) %}
    <a class=”{{ cssClass }}” href="#">Viewer</a>
    <a class=”{{ cssClass }}” href="#">Photo</a>
    <a class=”{{ cssClass }}” href="#">Video</a>
{% endmacro %}

{% from _self import input %}
```

Then you'd call it like this:

```
{{ input('dual') }}
```

If you don't need the value of the radio buttons for anything else, you could always give them the value of your CSS class; that way you don't need to convert them from one thing to another. If you did it this way then you could just call your macro like this:

```
{% set cssClass = entry.viewerOption %}
{{ input(cssClass) }}
```

Make sure you've set a default option for your radio button when you've added it in the Control Panel.